# What are the XP rewards for story missions in Destiny

Tags: destiny

I'm trying to figure out how much XP the story missions give in Destiny so I can figure out if it's worth playing / replaying them for XP to get to 20.

Does anyone have a list of missions and their XP rewards?  Do the XP rewards change for replaying story missions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XP rewards vary by level (and each mission can be attempted on a variety of difficulty levels). As for the XP rewards themselves, they can only be awarded once per mission, so repeating them on the same difficulty will not yield an XP reward (you can note this by hovering the mission, the rewards section will not include the XP bonus).

The bonus is somewhere in the range of 1k xp for levels 1-5 (early earth), 2k xp for levels 5-10 (earth and moon), 3k xp for levels 10-15 (moon and venus), and 4k xp for levels 15-20 (venus and mars).

Basically your best bet is to complete bounties and the story line. There is also another reason to do the story line while leveling: *when you reach 20 you will not automatically unlock any of the missions*. This means if you wish to do any bounties in the future or farm from specific places you will not be able to until you complete the missions - so they might as well get done while leveling.

It is best to complete the story line in order to unlock all of the missions. If you start from level 1 this will leave you at roughly level 17 when you finish the last mission on Mars. The last 3 levels may be completed by revisiting strikes, missions at their hardest available setting, or in the Crucible - but will be done fastest by doing the daily bounties.

Comment: ```when you reach 20 you will not unlock any of the missions``` so my Warlock, who I reached level 20 on Venus, is permanently blocked from certain missions? Can you provide any references?

Comment: @Thebluefish - No, not permanently blocked. You just still need to do the missions to unlock Mars or other missions :) I have a level 27 Titan I farm with who cannot even get to Venus.

Comment: That was weirdly worded. No wonder I didn't run into any difficulties on my way to 31 :p

Comment: @Thebluefish - It was worded poorly, I agree. I made an edit to hopefully clarify it.

Comment: "The last 3 levels may be completed by revisiting ... missions at their hardest available setting" You don't get bonus XP for redoing missions on a harder difficulty setting.  You are only awarded an XP bonus for completing a story mission the first time on any difficulty.  Higher level enemies don't yield more experience either, if that's what you were implying.

Comment: @turbo - So your issue was with "at their hardest available setting"? I noted that missions only give the reward once already. Are you certain that enemies yield the same experience regardless of their level? That would indicate that every enemy has a fixed xp gained, do you know what it is or have some citation for that?

Comment: Yes, it seemed to make the prior statement ambiguous. I don't have a source but I am fairly certain. It can easily be tested with an earn 9k exp without dying bounty. Different enemies give differing amounts of exp, and I believe the ultra/major status also affects exp but not level differences of red health bar enemies.